# commit a Queue in threadpool

Tags: c#, threadpool

I am starting an thread using threadpool like this:

```
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(outp), (object)new object[] { output});
```

output is a Queue.

This is the caled function:

```
    private void outp(object obj)
    {
        object[] arg = obj as object[];
        Queue<String> output = arg[0];
    }
```

Problem: arg[0] could not be converted to Queue. How can comit the Queue correctly to the threadpool?

Comment: Queue<String> output = (Queue<String>)arg[0];

Answer (score 0):

Pass queue, instead of array:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(outp), output);
```

Use queue:

```
private void outp(object obj)
{
    Queue<string> output = obj as Queue<string>;
    // use queue here
}
```

---

BTW you don't need to create callback delegate explicitly. Just pass method:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(outp, output);
```

Also consider to use [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) if several threads accessing your queue concurrently.